# VPS сервер, IPv6, настройка домена и добавления записи типа АААА

Tags: vps, домен, настройка, запись, ipv6

Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня есть VPS сервер и я хочу узнать что такое IPv6 и обязательно ли добавление его в записи, в настройке домена? Если да, то как это сделать? То есть что нужно конкретно вводить в поле "Субдомен" и в поле "Данные"?

Comment: Не обязательно. AAAA-записи ничем не отличаются от A-записей кроме использования IPv6